# What is the description of increasing frequency&decreasing wavelength in terms of the propagation of E&M fields in EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

EM radiation is considered to be propagating electric & magnetic fields through space. (is this incorrect?)

When the frequency then increases (and wavelength decreases), does this mean the E&M fields themselves have decreased spans of time in existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromagnetic radiation are propagating waves of intrinsically connected electric and magnetic field. The frequency has nothing to do with spans of time in existence unless you consider the frequency dependent absorption of light in matter. In vacuum, in the absence of interaction with matter, EM radiation should propagate as long as the universe exists.